# Adding roles in symfony 4 after authetification

Tags: symfony, roles

Is it possible to add some roles to the user in symfony 4 after the user is logged ? For instance, if you go to a certain page, I want to add some roles taken from database for the user without any re-authentification process.

Comment: What shall be the purpose of these "roles" on these certain pages? Do you want to persist these additional roles in your database and have them re-applied for further requests ... or do you want to achieve more fine-grained access-control like granting access to a resource only to a smaller subset of users?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the token.

```
$roles = array_merge($user->getRoles(), ['ROLE_EXTRA']);

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', roles);

$this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
```

This usecase is highly irregular though, so you might want to think it over.

Also, take a look at security.yml

```
security:
    always_authenticate_before_granting: true
```

This might override your roles, by re-authenticating. (I don't know for sure.) Set it to false if needed.